# How to use IBM bluemix object store with parse server fileadapter

Tags: ibm-cloud, parse-server, object-storage

I would like to integrate parse server to [IBM object store](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-serversdk-nodejs). Could you please guide me regarding this.
I am referring to configuring [file Adapters](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/blob/master/src/Adapters/Files/FilesAdapter.js)

Comment: To get a good answer, please provide more information, for example what is your environment? What results are you trying to achieve? What have you tried so far?

Comment: parse server is providing file adatper solution for two cloud platforms [AWS and Google cloud](http://parseplatform.github.io/docs/parse-server/guide/#configuring-file-adapters) looking for similar setup in bluemix cloud platform.

Answer (score 0):

Bluemix Object Storage uses OpenStack Swift. Based on my searches I don't see a Parser Server file Adapter for Swift.

Comment: Bluemix provides SDK in node.js, [bluemix-objectstorage-serversdk-nodejs](http://www.github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bluemix-objectstorage-serversdk-nodejs) . I would like to use this library and integrate with [parse file adapter](http://www.github.com/parse-community/parse-server/blob/master/src/Adapters/Files/FilesAdapter.js)